# C++ Proper Methodology for vectors of structs

Tags: c++, struct

So imagine I have a struct

```
struct Square{
  int width;
  int height;
};
```

Then i have a function somewhere in my code

```
void create_vec_squares(std::vector<Square> &dest){  
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //create squares and put then into the destination vector
    }
}
```

What is considered the proper way to do this in C++? I know some C, and my immediate thought is to use memory allocation techniques such as malloc. But, i will need to throw in a void delete_vec_squares(...) to make sure the memory is properly freed.

I was wondering if any issues could arise with this method

```
void create_vec_squares(std::vector<Square> &dest){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int val1,val2;
        //generate some values for squares
        ...
        //end generation
        dest.push_back({val1, val2});
    }
}
```

From my understanding, instead of allocating memory on the heap, the structures will simply be pushed onto the stack and there will be no need for manual memory allocation techniques;

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using malloc in C++ unless truly necessary, but instead `new` and `delete`, and even then, many times automatic memory is preferred over dynamic memory. Also, `vector`'s libraries already has methods designed for use with `std::vector`, for example the `push_back` to create new elements for the vector

Comment: Yes `malloc()` only to use `realloc()` after, and if the object has no constructor. Otherwise always `new`.

Comment: Your `dest.push_back({val1, val2});` is exactly what should be done... problem solved. But your understanding about it is wrong... the `push_back` ensures the vector-managed dynamic (heap) memory is adequate (resizing it if not), then adds the new value alongside any existing values there on the heap. The `vector` management object itself may be on the stack, heap, or a global, but the data's always on the heap.  Separately, during `push_back` (but not if you use `emplace_back`) there may be a temporary on the stack from which a copy is taken for the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of allocating memory on the heap, the structures will simply be pushed onto the stack and there will be no need for manual memory allocation techniques;

You are right. When you *push_back*, you just need to *push_back*, because

```
std::vector<T>::push_back(const T & val);
```

is **copy-based**.

Your `Square` object will be safely kept in `std::vector<Square>` out of scope.

If you do some allocation in `Square`, then it's `Square::~Square()`'s job to free what's needed to be.

Comment: So even if i had `Square s` then later said `s.height = 10; s.width = 20`. when i `dest.push_back(s)` it will safely copy the structure?

Comment: Yes, you can pass object as arguments, as long as it coincides with the vector's type

Comment: Yes. `dest.push_back(s)` will copy the `s`, as it exactly is. Why don't you just try yourself? It's simple to write and test.

Answer (score 0):

`push_back` is a vector method that adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element.

You can do the following:

```
void create_vec_squares(std::vector<Square> &dest){  
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //create an object Square and lets call it newSquare, then you can use push_back
        dest.push_back(newSquare); 
        //this will add your object newSquare at the end of vector dest
    }
}
```

And if you want to empty the vector entirely, you can use `dest.clear()`.By using the included methods it decreases the chances of mismanaging an object `vector` and is generally safer.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if any issues could arise with this method

```
void create_vec_squares(std::vector<Square> &dest){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int val1,val2;
        //generate some values for squares
        ...
        //end generation
        dest.push_back({val1, val2});
    }
}
```

The only issue with this method is that your code might not be portable. Some places are still stuck with C++03 compilers, which doesn't have uniform initialization.

With regard to the proper methodology, there is no one proper methodology.  Uniform initialization is great when you can use it. You can't always use it (even in C++11 and higher). Sometimes you need to use an explicit constructor, sometimes you need to operate on the item before adding it to the container. There's still no need for `new` and `delete`. Just declare a local variable and push that back onto the container.

When you know you are going to drop a boatload of objects onto a vector, it can be advantageous to reserve some space for that incoming boatload. Your code with a boatload (10000) objects instead of just 10:

```
void create_vec_squares(std::vector<Square> &dest){
    dest.reserve(dest.size() + 10000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        int val1,val2;
        //generate some values for squares
        ...
        //end generation
        dest.push_back({val1, val2});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly know that ten objects are to be set in `dest`, the following approach may be cleaner and faster:

```
struct Square{
  int width;
  int height;

  Square & set(int p_width, int p_height) {
      width = p_width; height = p_height;
      return (*this);
  }
};

typedef std::vector<Square> Square_vec;
void create_vec_squares(Square_vec & dest){  
    //create squares
    dest.reasize(10);
    for(Square_vec::iterator v_i = dest.begin(), v_e = dest.end(); v_i < v_e; ++v_i){
        // and put then into the destination vector
        v_i->set(val1, val2); //The already created Square object is set whithout temporary.
        //Or if you have common temporay Square object:
        *v_i = tmpSquare;
    }
}
```

Next step of refactorring may be creating a functor for filling up Square_vec substituted into the `for_each` function from `<algorithm>` instead of the `for(Square_vec::iterator ...` loop.